# EclipseLink QueryException without cache

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I turned off the EclipseLink cache because I'm modifying data externally and don't want the hassle of having to manually refresh everything. Apparently, this is the correct way to switch off the cache in persistence.xml to avoid object identity issues:

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
</properties>
```

And here's the exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6094] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The parameter name [patient_id] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="file:/C:/dev/repsitory/trunk/java/server/myapp-server/myapp-server-ear/target/gfdeploy/au.com.myapp_myapp-server-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-server-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar/_myappPU590288694" referenceClass=PatientRecord sql="SELECT active, new_patient, patient_id_external, rank, patient_id, clinic_system_id FROM postgres.myapp.patient_record WHERE (patient_id = ?)")
```

I can't even understand the exception message. It's talking about parameter names in the query, but JDBC parameters aren't named.

Any idea how to work around this without switching the cache back on?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had created an instance of `PatientRecord` that included one or two detached objects (many-to-one from `PatientRecord`'s perspective). This wasn't a problem with caching on because those objects never became detached.

I merged the objects first then it worked.